# how to pass $(this) variable into another function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that is called when a button is pressed. This function calls another function with an ajax call. If/when this ajax is completed successfully, I would like the pressed button's class to change.

```
$(".followUser").click(function(){
    ...
    create_friendship(that.userId, that.friendId);
    ...
}
function create_friendship(user_id, friend_id){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    ...
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      variableForButtonHere.html("Request sent").removeClass("btn-default").addClass('btn-info');
```

So far, replacing variableForButtonHere with $(this) has not worked. I have put

```
      var mydata = $(this).data();
      window.alert(mydata.userId);
```

in both functions and in the first function it prints and in the second if prints `undefined`

I am assuming that  $(this) must somehow be passed into the second function. How do I do this?

Comment: There's no way of passing `$(this)` other than by parameter. There's no way of passing `this` either, other than by parameter.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli I thought so too, but then learned that the value of `this` depends on how a function is called. So, you can *set* the value of `this` depending on how you call your function. An example could be how `jQuery.proxy` function utilises it to change the value of `this`.

Comment: @RobinMailfait has answered in this way

Comment: I meant something else. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it quite easily like this:

```
$(".followUser").click(function(){
    ...
    create_friendship($(this), that.userId, that.friendId);
    ...
}
function create_friendship(button, user_id, friend_id){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    ...
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      button.html("Request sent").removeClass("btn-default").addClass('btn-info');
```

Comment: You are quite right, I will accept this answer when SO allows me.

Answer (score 2):

#### Option 1: Set context in your `$.ajax` call

`$.ajax` has an option that would allow you to set the value of `this` in the callback functions. It's `context`.

You can use it like this:

```
$(".followUser").click(function(){
    ...
    create_friendship(that.userId, that.friendId, this);
    ...
}
function create_friendship(user_id, friend_id, setThis){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    context: setThis,    // <=== HERE ===
    ...
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
     // === Now, `this` will refer to your button element!
     $(this).html("Request sent").removeClass("btn-default").addClass('btn-info');
```

#### Option 2: jQuery.proxy() method

Use [`jQuery.proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function to set the value of `this` in your method.

#### Option 3: Clean JavaScript method

Even better, you can use JavaScripts built in methods `call` and `apply` to set the value of `this` in your method calls.

```
$(".followUser").click(function(){
    ...
    create_friendship.call(this, that.userId, that.friendId);
    ...
}
function create_friendship(user_id, friend_id, setThis){
  // Here, you can either use `context: this,` option as in first method above
  // or set your variable like so:
  var button = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    ...
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
     // === Now, `this` will refer to your button element!
     button.html("Request sent").removeClass("btn-default").addClass('btn-info');
```